# Layout Main Section is Covered by Footer

Tags: html, css

I want the lorem impsum part to push the footer further down to bottom. But as you can see it gets covered by footer :(.

I tried overlapping methods but I dont want to scroll lorem ipsum section. I also tried flexbox but it did not work. Help please I am pulling my hair :S.

https://jsbin.com/buyosiduyi/edit?html,css,js,output

CSS

```
footer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #292929;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 70px 15px #888888;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #020202;
    font-size: 15px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I want footer to be on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can change css of #body-part

```
#body-part{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("mainpage.jpg");
    background-position: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

and remove `position:absolute;` from footer